# Video thumbnail image for android - Titanium

Tags: android, android-intent, video, titanium-mobile

I have a video and I need a thumbnail image for that video for android.This is what I created for iOS.

```
player.requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes([1],Titanium.Media.VIDEO_TIME_OPTION_NEAREST_KEYFRAME, function(response) {

if(response.success) {
  var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, videoName + ".png");                    
f.write(response.image);
```

So? What about android? How can it be done? This is what I done video capture for android. How can I create a thumbnail image for this?

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({
    action : 'android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE' //android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE
});

intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 15);
```

Comment: You can try this http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer-method-requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes

Answer (score -1):

You can get the thumbnail bitmap of video file by using code given below :

```
Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: This is for native Android not Titanium.